# How can I concatenate 2 variables to access array values?

Tags: templating, forloop

I am using [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900035/how-to-concatenate-two-twig-variables-in-a-twig-loop) to try to concatenate two variables in twig.

I am very close, but can't seem to get over the hump of rendering the correct syntax.

This is what I am currently using:

```
 {% for user in plugin.data.users %}
     ...  
     {{ attribute(user, 'foo' ~ loop.index0)|raw|nl2br.bar }}
     ...
 {% endfor %}
```

This is what I am currently getting back:

```
Key "foo0"... for array with keys "...does not exist."
```

What I am trying to create is `foo[0]`, `foo[1]` etc.

Well, I couldn't figure it out so this is how I did it. If there is a better way, I'd be happy to update the post.

```
{% set i = 0 %}
    {{ user.foo[i].bar }}
    ...
{% set i = i + 1 %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten a bit further into this that is *slightly* beyond the scope of my original question, but I think it's worth bringing up for the benefit of others (like me).

To answer my original question, this is how I was able to make it work:

```
{% set i = 0 %}
    {{ user.foo[i].bar }}
    ...
{% set i = i + 1 %}
```

However, if your templates start to become more complex, and/or need more or different types of looping, you might want to consider looking at a [template hook](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#hook-detail)

This works pretty slick. Let's say I am getting data from an api or some other service (using a plugin). This is how you would use a hook.

**template.twig**

```
...
{% hook 'myAwesomeHook' %}
```

Since it is recommended to place the hook logic in the `init` method of your plugin, this is what that would look like:

**MyPlugin.php**

```
...
public function init() {
    craft->template()->hook('myAwesomeHook', function(&$context) {
       foreach($context['user'] as $user) {
         return $user; // or do whatever you need.
       }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try and access the array that `user.foo` would have.
So your code would be something like:

```
 {% for user in plugin.data.users %}
  ...  
  {{ attribute(user.foo, loop.index0)|raw|nl2br }}
  ...
 {% endfor %}
```

I haven't tested this though, just going by what I'm sure I remember doing once...

Comment: Thanks @Alec, I couldn't get it figured out using the `attribute` tag. I updated my question with how I got it to work.